# Advanced search using a text input to search through only one category

Tags: php, wordpress, search

The goal of this is to use as much core WordPress functionality as possible.

advanced.php - This is the custom search form...

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="search" value="post">

<input id="search-case-study" class="search-case-study" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..." name="s" />

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
```

functions.php

```
// CASE STUDY SEARCH
function advanced_search_query($query) {

    if($query->is_search()) {
        // category terms search.
        $query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'case-study',
                'field' => 'slug'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');
// END CASE STUDY SEARCH
```

I am also calling the form into the page using:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'advanced', 'searchform' ); ?>
```

The form pulls into the page properly.

The form contains the fields I wish to use.

I just need help creating the query within functions.php.

In my case, the slug for the category I wish to search is 'case-study', and it needs to search all the content within that category's blog posts. Returning the link, image, title.

Comment: The question is maybe a bit unclear: Are you saying you _only want the search_ to be within the ONE category `case-study`?  Is that the goal?

Comment: @cale_b - That is correct, thanks!

Comment: @cale_b - Thanks for the edits too

Answer (score 2):

The tax query doesn't quite work like that.  Your desired outcome should actually be somewhat simpler.

See your code, modified (with comments explaining what's going on):

```
function advanced_search_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_search() ) {
        // find the category by slug
        $term = get_category_by_slug( 'case-study' ); 
        // get the category ID
        $id = $term->term_id;
        // set the query argument to search within the category
        $query->set( 'cat', $cat_id );
    }

    // removed "return $query" - $query is passed by reference, so no need to return
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');
```

NOTE: This will cause *all searches* to be limited to this category.  Since I'm guessing that's not what you want, may I suggest making the following modifications to your form, as well as the function, so it only limits the search when the search originates with your form:

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="post">
    <input id="search-case-study" class="search-case-study" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..." name="s" />
    <!-- add a hidden input that passes the desired category slug -->
    <input name="cat_slug" value="case-study" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Then, update the functions.php function as follows:

```
function advanced_search_query( $query ) {
    // check if search AND if "cat_slug" input was present
    if( $query->is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['cat_slug'] ) ) {
        // find the category by the slug passed in the input
        $term = get_category_by_slug( $_GET['cat_slug'] ); 
        // defensive check, in case the category could not be found
        if ( ! empty( $term->term_id ) ) {
            // get the category ID
            $cat_id = $term->term_id;
            // set the query argument to search within the category
            $query->set( 'cat', $cat_id );
        }
    }

    // removed "return $query" - $query is passed by reference, so no need to return
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'advanced_search_query');
```

Comment: I have been testing this code. I can clearly see how it could work however the results are just not narrowed down as we planned. The search still runs through the product pages. If I change the action on the form to home_url('/blog/') it then filters down to the blog posts, but still not the specified category. I am also unable to search for anything related to the case study other than the title.

Comment: thanks again for returning to my question. 
`object(WP_Term)#13036 (16) { ["term_id"]=> int(211) ["name"]=> string(10) "Case Study" ["slug"]=> string(10) "case-study" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(211) ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "category" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(2) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["cat_ID"]=> int(211) ["category_count"]=> int(2) ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> string(10) "Case Study" ["category_nicename"]=> string(10) "case-study" ["category_parent"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: So as we can see it finds the category. I think there may be an issue with $cat_id not being defined. Also what should I do about the action on the form.

Comment: Yes, see my edit.  I had `$id = $term->term_id;` - which was a typo.  I've updated it so it's `$cat_id = $term->term_id;` - which should resolve it.